# How to show fps counter in Android 8?

Tags: applications, system, 8.0-oreo, overlay

In Oreo, is there a native way (preferred) or a 3rd party app that can show current screen refresh rate (fps counter), in the form of an overlay, in all situation (system UI, apps and 2D/3D games)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [FPS meter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ftpie.fpsmeter) or [GameBench (FPS counter without root)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gamebench.metricscollector). I am not sure but they both supports non-rooted phones.

Comment: Thank for the tips! I'll look into them. So, maybe there's no a native way to do it?

Comment: FPS meter doesn't seem to work with Android 6+, as mentioned it its app description page.

Comment: GameBench work on Android 7.1.1. Thanks.